# Check if background restriction data is enabled or not?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, restriction

I have a service which is running on the main thread not in the background. In the service I'm checking net connection via broadcastreciver. When I enable **restriction data enabled** in Settings, broadcastreciver is catching intent well, but internet connection(Mobile data) is disabled to my app although it has on my device. I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8996327/how-to-enable-the-background-data-settings-in-android), and [android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED).

```
intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED");
    intentFilter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");
    registerReceiver(this.connectionStatusReceiver, intentFilter);


private BroadcastReceiver connectionStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public synchronized void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        log.info("connection state changed");            
        checkConnectionState();
    }
};

 getActiveNetworkInfo() - *will always display CONNECTED when i switch on *restriction**
```

One more thing, when I switch on background data restrict, I checked `intent.getAction`. It always returns `android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE`.
How can I check background restriction data is switched on/off?

Comment: how can i get to know if user switch on _background data restrict_ in Settings on my app?

Answer (score 1):

You can check that from Android 7.0 (API 24) and above. Google added the howto in their android developer site. Here is the link [Optimizing Network Data Usage](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/data-saver.html)

Answer (score -1):

1.Use the following code to check whether the wifi or mobile data has been switched on or not.

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet()
    {

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = 
                             (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(
                              Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
          if (connectivity != null)
          {
              NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
              if (info != null)
                  for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                      if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                      {
                          return true;
                      }

          }
          return false;
    }
```

2. Then on basis of true or false, check for restricted data:

   ```
   if(isConnectingToInternet())
   {

         /*
         your code to check network state*/

   }
   ```